# How to change background color of list component using action script

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How to change backgroundcolor of list component using action script

Answer (score 2):

This is defined from the `contentBackgroundColor` style property of the `s:List`.

[image: list]

**MXML example:**

From MXML, set the `contentBackgroundColor` property of the `s:List` component.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:List contentBackgroundColor="0xabcdef">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:String>Item 1</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Item 2</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Item 3</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:List>

</s:Application>
```

**ActionScript example:**

From ActionScript, set style property: `setStyle("contentBackgroundColor", 0xabcdef);`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                list.setStyle("contentBackgroundColor", 0xabcdef);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:List id="list">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:String>Item 1</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Item 2</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Item 3</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:List>

</s:Application>
```

This could also be accomplished by creating a skin class for the list.